# Conditionally remove a node in XML document using XSL stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements

I have this XML-document, and I want to remove the Pnlty-node and all its children if the value in Id is equal to 05295.

```
<Root>
    <GenericTag>
        <twSender>akds</twSender>
        <NetworkInfo>
            <twService>okooko</twService>
        </NetworkInfo>
    </GenericTag>
    <Payload>
        <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:11111:tech:xsd:DRAFT5semt.000.001.002">
            <SpcKtp>
                <Pnlty>
                    <PtyId>
                        <Id>
                            <Id>
                                <HalwId>
                                    <Id>05295</Id>
                                    <Issr>VPDK</Issr>
                                </HalwId>
                            </Id>
                        </Id>
                     </PtyId>
                  </Pnlty>
             </SpcKtp>
        </Document>
    </Payload>
 </Root>
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
<Root>
    <GenericTag>
        <twSender>akds</twSender>
        <NetworkInfo>
            <twService>okooko</twService>
        </NetworkInfo>
    </GenericTag>
    <Payload>
        <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:11111:tech:xsd:DRAFT5semt.000.001.002">
            <SpcKtp>
            </SpcKtp>
        </Document>
    </Payload>
 </Root>
```

I have tried with this XSL-stylesheet in XML-validator 3.1.0.1

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- The identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- The empty template for what I want to NOT copy -->
    <xsl:template match = "Root/Payload/Document/SpcKtp/Pnlty/Id/Id/HalwId/Id= '05295'"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it does not work.

I have played around with the empty template to try to figure out what might be the issue.

```
<xsl:template match = "Root/Payload/Document"/>
```

And this does NOT remove the node Document (and none of its children).

However, this line works differently:

```
<xsl:template match = "Root/Payload"/>
```

It removes the node Payload and all its children. That is, it does not copy it with the identity transformation.

So I figured that it could be a problem with the attribute in the node  and I thus tried:

```
<xsl:template match = "Root/Payload/Document |@*"/>
```

and some variants of it, including hard coding the value of the xmlns attribute.
Nothing. To me it seems as if the node Document is "blocking" the path where I can evaluate the condition. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I have just started looking at the possibility to use local-name to "bypass" the need for the name spaces. Would you say it is worth investigating? I am considering placing a new question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
<!-- The empty template for what I want to NOT copy -->
<xsl:template match="Root/Payload/iso:Document/iso:SpcKtp/iso:Pnlty[iso:PtyId/iso:Id/iso:Id/iso:HalwId/iso:Id = '05295']" xmlns:iso="urn:iso:std:iso:11111:tech:xsd:DRAFT5semt.000.001.002"/>
```

Comment: What about the xmlns= declaration on the Document element?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, your suggestion did not provide any progress. I tried putting the [ parantheses] in different places, but not luck. Keep an eye on this question, hopefully we will reach a solution here.

Comment: @MichaelKay, good point, overlooked that.

Comment: @MårtenCronander, I overlooked the namespace that some of your elements have, so the code, while need a predicate, needs further fixes in terms of a namespace declaration. Will edit the answer to show that.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I tried your edited solution and unfortunately it does not work. The xml-file is copied in its entirety. Could it help to declare the xmlns:iso="..." in the  <xsl:stylesheet version...> tag?

Comment: @MårtenCronander, sorry, the namespace is right but I relied on the XPath in your sample which missed one step, now added.

Comment: [at]MichaelKay
[at]MartinHonnen

YESS!!! Thank you! It works now. My family thanks you, for now I can be a happy person the whole weekend.
Love! <3

Answer (score 1):

You can't just ignore namespaces. In your path you need to write something like

```
match = "Root/Payload/d:Document/d:SpcKtp/d:Pnlty...."
```

and declare `xmlns:d="urn:iso:std:iso:11111:tech:xsd:DRAFT5semt.000.001.002"`

Comment: Thank you for answering. Since I am rather new at this, I have to double check that I have understood your suggestions correctly. (Most likely some things have gone awry.)
This is how I tried to implement your suggestions:
Declaring:
<xsl xmlns:d="urn:iso:std:iso:11111:tech:xsd:DRAFT5semt.000.001.002"/>
and the match:
<xsl:template match = "Root/Payload/d:Document/d:SpcKtp/d:Pnlty/d:Id/d:Id/d:HalwId/d:Id= '05295'"/>.

The way I did it, did not work. But that is not the way you intended, right?